# Pandas assign series to another Series based on index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, assign

I have three Pandas Dataframes:

`df1`:

```
0        NaN
1        NaN
2        NaN
3        NaN
4        NaN
5        NaN
6        NaN
7        NaN
8        NaN
9        NaN
```

`df2`:

```
0        1
3        7
6        5
9        2
```

`df3`:

```
1        2
4        6
7        6
```

My goal is to assign the values of `df2` and `df3` to `df1` based on the index.
`df1` should then become:

```
0        1
1        2
2        NaN
3        7
4        6
5        NaN
6        5
7        6
8        NaN
9        2
```

I tried with simple assinment:

```
df1.loc[df2.index] = df2.values
```

or

```
df1.loc[df2.index] = df2
```

but this gives me an ValueError:
`ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do `concat` with `combine_first`:

```
pd.concat([df2,df3]).combine_first(df1)
```

Or `reindex`:

```
pd.concat([df2,df3]).reindex_like(df1)
```

---

```
0  1.0
1  2.0
2  NaN
3  7.0
4  6.0
5  NaN
6  5.0
7  6.0
8  NaN
9  2.0
```

Comment: Hey anky, thanks! I can see how it works. For some reason I get an error: `NotImplementedError: cannot align with a higher dimensional NDFramedf_rsi_combined`. I think it's because of the way I create my `df1` to have a DataFrame filled with NaN of a specific length. I do: `df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=range(10))`. How could I fix this?

Comment: curious, `concat + reindex` is much faster that `concat + combine_first`

Comment: @smaica colums mismatch, try `df1['yourDesiredCol'] = df1.index.map(pd.concat([df2,df3]).squeeze())
` @RomanPerekhrest combine_first is unfortunately slow as reindex just maps/broadcasts  columns whereas combine first has to check underlying arrays, however it is but a viable option depending on the usecase a